# Как исправить это предупреждение в pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Написал код:

```py
OverAll = []

courses = df[['Math_PassStatus', 'Reading_PassStatus', 'Writing_PassStatus']]

for val in courses.values:
    if 'F' not in val:
        OverAll.append('P')
    else:
        OverAll.append('F')

courses['OverAll_PassStatus'] = OverAll

print(f"Экзамен сдали {courses.OverAll_PassStatus.value_counts()['P']} человек")
```

Предупреждение:

```py
C:\Users\Oskarr\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9044/4146853526.py:12: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  courses['OverAll_PassStatus'] = OverAll
```

Понимаю, что нужно использовать .loc, но где именно - нет. Только начинаю изучать pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
courses = df[['Math_PassStatus', 'Reading_PassStatus', 'Writing_PassStatus']]
...
courses['OverAll_PassStatus'] = OverAll
```

`courses` - это некий срез датафрейма `df`, в этом проблема. Методы решения могут быть разные, например, если `courses` будет и дальше независимым датафреймом, то лучше явно сказать, что это нормальная копия выборки из исходного датафрейма, предупреждение должно исчезнуть:

```py
courses = df[['Math_PassStatus', 'Reading_PassStatus', 'Writing_PassStatus']].copy()
                                                                             ^^^^^^^
```

К сожалению, предупреждения не всегда чётко подсказывают, что нужно делать. Но суть тут передана верно - вы присваиваете что-то выборке из датафрейма, это не есть хорошо.

Другой вариант избавиться от предупреждения - добавить новую колонку в исходный датафрейм и использовать дальше его:

```py
df['OverAll_PassStatus'] = OverAll
print(f"Экзамен сдали {df.OverAll_PassStatus.value_counts()['P']} человек")
```

Comment: То есть, если срез не будет больше нигде использоваться, то лучше его просто скопировать из основного датафрейма?

Comment: Наоборот - если вы его хотите и дальше использовать как самостоятельную сущность, то скопировать. Как вариант вы тут могли присвоить новую колонку в исходный `df`, тогда не нужно было бы ничего копировать. Это как-раз был бы вариант, что вы использовали срез как временную переменную, а дальше она вам уже не нужна.

Comment: понял, спасибо еще раз